# Open-Source Applications using Java JMS?

Tags: java, jms

Does anyone know of open-source applications that are built on top of Java JMS? I am looking to find applications so I can study them and see how they are used.

[This earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035949/real-world-use-of-jms-message-queues) has examples of hypothetical uses for JMS, but I am looking for actual code!

Thanks,
Nels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache CXF supports JMS as a transport for SOAP messages. Lots of source code to read.

Comment: Just to elaborate, the code bmargulies is talking about is in the org.apache.cxf.transport.jms package, which is inside of the cxf-rt-transports-jms directory of the CXF project.

Furthermore, looks like the Spring framework is similarly layered on top of JMS.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking to learn the JMS API?  If so, it is actually one of the simplest parts of Java EE so you shouldn't have a problem finding more specific help here.

To answer your question more specifically, have you looked at [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [JBoss Messaging](http://www.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/)? Both are open source JMS providers and they have a lot of API examples and documentation on their sites.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks, but actually my intentions are a little more sinister. :-)

I am working on a research project that helps to ensure that programmers are using APIs correctly. JMS is one of the APIs I am looking at, and so I wanted to find some programs that use it for case studies. Thanks, nonetheless.