# JMS and AMQP - RabbitMQ

Tags: java, jms, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I am trying to understand what JMS and how it is connected to AMQP terminology.
I know JMS is an API and AMQP is a protocol.

Here are my assumptions (and questions as well)

- RabbitMQ uses AMQP protocol (rather implements AMQP protocol)
- Java clients need to use AMQP protocol client libraries to connect / use RabbitMQ
- Where does JMS API come into play here? JMS API should use AMQP client libraries to connect to RabbitMQ?
- Usually we use JMS to connect Message brokers like RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc. Then what is the default protocol used here instead of AMQP?

Some of the above may be dumb. :-) But trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @KevinRave: The selected answer is wrong on some main points it makes. I have added a comment so that you can look at it.

Comment: @KevinRave I have edited the answer.Now The controversial portion has replaced.Now the whole answer is perfectly OK

Comment: I dont know who edited my answer and gave this improper point which was at num 3.. because I already have asked the thing which kevin is saying at point 2.Always read carefully before down voting or making suggestions

Comment: Have a look at the JMS section in this article. It has a very detailed explanation http://saipraveenblog.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/asynchronous-communication-in-soamsa/

Comment: RabbitMQ Tutorial - https://jstobigdata.com/rabbitmq/complete-rabbitmq-tutorial-in-java/

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Your question is a bit messy but Let's see its bits one by one.

General concept:

The Java Message Service **(JMS) API is a Java Message Oriented Middleware (MOM) API for sending messages between two or more clients**. JMS is a part of the Java Platform, Enterprise Edition, and is defined by a specification developed under the Java Community Process as JSR 914. **It is a messaging standard that allows application components based on the Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE) to create, send, receive, and read messages. It allows the communication between different components of a distributed application to be loosely coupled, reliable, and asynchronous**.

*Now* (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol)):

> **The Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP)** is an open standard application layer protocol for message-oriented middleware. The
> defining features of AMQP are message orientation, queuing, routing
> (including point-to-point and publish-and-subscribe), reliability and
> security.

And the most important thing (again from Wikipedia):

> Unlike JMS, which merely defines an API, AMQP is a wire-level
> protocol. A wire-level protocol is a description of the format of the
> data that is sent across the network as a stream of octets.
> Consequently any tool that can create and interpret messages that
> conform to this data format can interoperate with any other compliant
> tool irrespective of implementation language

Some important things you should know:

1. Keep in mind that AMQP is a messaging technology that do not implement the JMS API.
2. JMS is API and AMQP is a protocol.So it doesn't make sense to say that what is default protocol of JMS, of course client
   applications use HTTP/S as the connection protocol when invoking a
   WebLogic Web Service.
3. JMS is only a API spec. It doesn't use any protocol. A JMS provider (like ActiveMQ) could be using any underlying protocol to
   realize the JMS API. For ex: Apache ActiveMQ can use any of the
   following protocols: AMQP, MQTT, OpenWire, REST(HTTP), RSS and Atom,
   Stomp, WSIF, WS Notification, XMPP. I suggest you read [Using
   JMS Transport as the Connection Protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv_rpc/jmstransport.html#wp244314).

Good Luck :)

Comment: `I am not sure but I believe that AMQP also uses HTTP/S protocol but AMQP is enhacement is messaging protocol over HTTP` : **No. That is not correct.** `JMS uses simple HTTP but for RabbitMQ/ActiveMq, they uses enhanced protocol.` : **No. That is not correct.** JMS is only a API spec. It doesnt use any protocol. A JMS provider (like ActiveMQ) could be using any underlying protocol to realize the JMS API. For ex: Apache ActiveMQ can use any of the following protocols: AMQP, MQTT, OpenWire, REST(HTTP), RSS and Atom, Stomp, WSIF, WS Notification, XMPP.

Comment: I have edited the answer.Now The controversial portion has replaced.

Comment: @brainOverflow I dont know who edited my answer and gave this improper point which was at num 3.. because I have asked the thing which you are saying at point 2.Always read carefully before down voting or making suggestions

Comment: i already added stuff from that PDF so you can go to some other links too

Comment: AMQP is not a wire-level protocol. Wikipedia is wrong , omg, who would have thunk it

Answer (score 51):

Let's start from the basis.

**RabbitMQ** *is a MOM* (Message Oriented Middleware), developed with Erlang (a TLC-oriented programming language) and **implementing the wire protocol AMQP** (Advance Message Queuing Protocol). 
Currently, many Client APIs (e.g., Java, C++, RESTful, etc.) are available to enable the usage of RabbitMQ messaging services.

**JMS** (Java Messaging Service) is a JCP standard defining a **set of structured APIs** to be implemented by a MOM. An example of MOM that implements (i.e. is compatible with) the JMS APIs is ActiveMQ; there's also HornetMQ, and others. Such middlewares get the JMS APIs and implement the exchange patterns accordingly.

According to above, taken the skeleton of JMS APIs, an instance of RabbitMQ and its Java Client APIs, it is possible to develop a JMS implementation making use of RabbitMQ: the only thing that one has to do, at that point, is implementing the exchange pattern (over RabbitMQ) according to the JMS specification.

The key is: *a set of APIs, like JMS, can be implemented no matter of the technology* (in this case, RabbitMQ).

Comment: What does TLC stand for?

Comment: @mvmm TLC stands for Telecommunication. Please, have a look to [1].

[1] https://www.allacronyms.com/TLC/Telecommunication

Answer (score 16):

JMS, when it was defined did not define a protocol between the JMS client and a messaging server. The JMS client, which implement the JMS API can use whatever protocol to communicate with messaging server. The client just need to be compliant with JMS api. Thats all. Ususally JMS clients use a custom protocol that their messaging server understands.

AMQP on other hand is a protocol between a messaging client and messaging server. A JMS client can use AMQP as the protocol to communicate with the messaging server. And there are clients like that available.

http://www.lshift.net/blog/2009/03/16/openamqs-jms-client-with-rabbitmq-server

Answer (score 2):

- Where does JMS API come into play here? JMS API should use AMQP client libraries to connect to RabbitMQ?

JMS is an API, so some JMS API's are implemented over the AMQP protocol (like [Apache QPID JMS](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html)) while most JMS APIs use other protocols. If the version of the AMQP protocol is the same, such a client should be able to communicate with another AMQP client.

- Usually we use JMS to connect Message brokers like RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc. Then what is the default protocol used here instead of AMQP?

It depends on your configuration of that JMS API. For ActiveMQ, it could be [AMQP](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html) but by default it is 'openwire'

Answer (score 2):

### What is JMS?

JMS is a Java standard that defines a common API for working with message brokers.

### Why do we need JMS?

1. **It was introduced in *2001*** and was adopted approach for a very long time for asynchronous messaging.
2. **Before JMS, what used to happen was each message broker had a proprietary API, making an application’s messaging code less portable between brokers**.
3. With JMS, all compliant implementations can be worked with via a common
   interface. So, if you are changing your broker say "*Apache Active MQ*" to "*Apache ActiveMQ Artemis*" you don't have to worry about the portability issues as the JMS interface ensures your code portability.

### Cons of JMS?

1. JMS in 2001, when it was defined didn't enforce any protocol between the JMS client and the JMS messaging server. JMS client could have used any protocol for communication and the client needed to make sure a protocol that was compliant with the JMS API.
2. JMS is limited to Java applications.

---

### What is AMQP?

1. AMQP (Advanced Message Queuing Protocol) is kind of an open standard application layer protocol for delivering messages.
2. **AMQP 0.9.1 was published in November 2008.**
3. AMQP provides a description of how a message should be constructed. Unlike JMS, it doesn't provide an API on how the message should be sent.

### Why AMQP?

1. AMQP is just a protocol between a messaging client and the messaging server. So even a JMS client can use AMQP as the protocol to communicate with the messaging server.
2. AMQP is a messaging protocol that stands across all platforms. It doesn't matter which AMQP client is used, as long as it's an AMQP complaint, it will hold.

Answer (score 1):

JMS is an API from Sun - Oracle.
There are drivers that implement this API. For each language and each messaging system, there will be at least one driver. E.g. for Java + RabbitMQ -> a driver, for Java + ActiveMq, for C# + RabbitMQ, Go + IBM MQ etc.
AMQP is a wire level protocol much like MQTT or STOMP or Openwire. It is not an API. This brings up two new things:-

1. Messaging system may need a plugin to support the wire level protocol, e.g. ActiveMQ STOMP plugin etc.
2. Driver needs to support the wire level protocol by converting standard JMS API calls to STOMP, aMQP etc calls.
   Finally, thus you can have one driver per -> messaging system + API + wire level protocol
   Java code -> API -> Driver -> wire level protocol -> plugin -> Messaging system

Answer (score 0):

https://spring.io/understanding/AMQP

> AMQP (Advanced Message Queueing Protocol) is an openly published wire
>   specification for asynchronous messaging. Every byte of transmitted
>   data is specified. This characteristic allows libraries to be written
>   in many languages, and to run on multiple operating systems and CPU
>   architectures, which makes for a truly interoperable, cross-platform
>   messaging standard.
>
> AMQP is often compared to JMS (Java Message Service), the most common
>   messaging system in the Java community. A limitation of JMS is that
>   the APIs are specified, but the message format is not. Unlike AMQP,
>   JMS has no requirement for how messages are formed and transmitted.
>   Essentially, every JMS broker can implement the messages in a
>   different format. They just have to use the same API.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you may be looking for [this documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabricRabbitMQ32/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.rabbitmq.3.2/jms-client/about.html) which says, in part:

> JMS Client for vFabric RabbitMQ is a client library for vFabric
>   RabbitMQ. vFabric RabbitMQ is not a JMS provider but has features
>   needed to support the JMS Queue and Topic messaging models. JMS Client
>   for RabbitMQ implements the JMS 1.1 specification on top of the
>   RabbitMQ Java client API, thus allowing new and existing JMS
>   applications to connect with RabbitMQ brokers through Advanced Message
>   Queueing Protocol (AMQP).

Comment: Nope. Its not the one I was looking at. But similar.