# When and where to use JMS?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, jms

In many books and blog posts people give JMS as an example for inter-applications connections and communications. 
Can you give a brief explanation of when and where to use it and why not using other protocols like HTTP (Rest and SOAP ) ? Please provide some JMS use cases ?

Comment: JMS is not a protocol, you can't compare it with rest or soap

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real world use of JMS/message queues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035949/real-world-use-of-jms-message-queues)

Answer (score 1):

JMS is described as API for sending messages between two or more clients, but actually is more *Server-to-Server oriented*. So about `JMS use cases` - in my experience I saw that JMS is used mostly in inner networks (behind firewalls etc.) so the modules can not only swap info, but also be *orchestrated*.