# Expensive operations in scheduled Spring method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a method with `@Scheduled` annotation. This method contains long running, expensive operations. I'm afraid that the application slows down when the scheduled method starts running. Is there any way to assign a priority to the scheduled method? What is the best practice to start a low priority background process in Spring?

Comment: Maybe instead of @Scheduled you should send it to JMS? Please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035949/real-world-use-of-jms-message-queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setThreadPriority` method on the task scheduler.  This will set the priority for all Threads in the underlying pool.  See [java.lang.thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for pre-defined priorities.

Comment: Thx, it worked.

    <bean id="threadPoolTaskScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
        <property name="poolSize" value="3" />
        <property name="threadPriority" value="1" />
    </bean>