# Java Event driven Pub/Sub system Subscriber is slower than Producers

Tags: java, guava, publish-subscribe

I have to design a system where Subscriber is slower than Producers. I cannot use any MQ solution(due to budget constraints). Can I use in-memory queue where the producer will put data into queue and Subscriber will poll in a specific interval? How to implement using Java 7.

Can I use Google Guava EventBus for the same?

If yes either of the cases then how to implement the solution or any other low cost alternative solution.

Comment: Use a BlockingQueue to apply back pressure.

Comment: Could you please explain it more.

Comment: Can I use it with Google Guava EventBus?

Answer (score 0):

An `EventBus` is good for decoupling parts of the system, so that the producers only knows the `EventBus` and the consumers knows it indirectly by means of `@Subscribe` (some code must know both the consumer and the `EventBus`, so it can call `register`).

You may or may not need such decoupling. The `EventBus` may deliver events synchronously on the same thread (the default) or using a provided `Executor`. If you don't want the producers to be slowed down by the subscribers, then you can use the asynchronous version.

If you want that the producers don't get slowed down, then you may use some `BlockingQueue` from `java.util.concurrent`. Look at `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ArrayBlockingQueue`, if you want to apply backpressure (i.e., to slow down the produces if the queue grows big).

If you don't care that both producers and consumers must see your queue, then you don't need an `EventBus`. If you do, then you can use it e.g., so that the producers post an event subscribed by a thread filling the queue. Or there may be a thread polling the queue and posting to the bus.

Or both, but don't over-engineer it, just [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

AFAICT, proper message queue is an [overkill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1035949/581205) when working inside of a single Java process.

You should add more details to get a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My requirement is producer and subscriber shouldn't know each other. There can be multiple subscribers for a given input type. A producer will push messages and Subscriber will read it one by one at its own pace. Please let me know if you have any other suggestion. I am using Spring 4, Java 7 etc.