# How can we handle IPC between objective C and Python?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, ipc

I need to make Inter-Process Communication between python and objective-C. Both processes should be in a local machine. So which IPC mechanism is best and shall I get any scratch for develop?

Comment: May this help: [How can I handle IPC between C and Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16120373/2037229)

Answer (score 0):

> So which IPC mechanism is best and shall I get any scratch for
>   develop?

is very difficult to assess. Pure IPC includes message passing, shared memory, etc... Much depends on the data you are trying to communicate (eg. is data length constant or fixed? Is it binary or pure text? Is the data much or little?

Here's a simple example using shared memory, between C and Python: http://jcoppens.com/univ/iua/str/prog/shm_python.tar.gz

You'll need the sysv_ipc module for Python.

Message passing (msgget and friends) is slightly more flexible - in my opinion.

Comment: The data length is fixed, and we passed it as a binary. data is little.

Comment: Shared memory or message passing are both good options for that. Have a look at the ipc library (both in C and Python) on how to do it. And the example I mentioned above.