# Compatibility of JSON-RPC across Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, json

I have a process running Python code, and another running C++. Each needs to make RPC calls into the other within the same host. I'd like to have a single tool, implemented in both languages, to reduce compatibility issues, but there is no Python/C++ entry in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC  .

If I use one library (say simple-rpc) in Python and a different one (say libjson-rpc-cpp) in C++, could there be compatibility issues? JSON-RPC 2.0 is supposed to be a standard but there could be corner cases or grey areas.

Looking for pointers and real-world experience, including exception handling (do Python exceptions show up in C++ and vv).

I know about Protocol Buffers: they are cross-language but not exactly a RPC mechanism.

EDIT: Just found Apache Thrift, but it seems to have many dependences. Still interested in original question on using different libraries on Python/C++ side.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915191/simple-ipc-between-c-and-python-cross-platform

Comment: only thing missing in the above thread is probably CORBA

Comment: Thanks, Basav. CORBA seems too heavyweight. The [thread  you quoted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915191/simple-ipc-between-c-and-python-cross-platform) refers to IPC, not RPC, but it is a good pointer.