# Data transfer between C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, data-transfer

I would like to share memory between C++ and Python.

My problem:

1. I am working with big data sets (up to 6 GB of RAM) in C++. All calculations are done in c++.
2. Then, I want to "paste" all my results to a Python program. But I can only write my data on disk, and then read that file from Python, which is not efficient.

Is there any way to "map" memory corresponding to C++ variables so that I may access the data from Python? I don't want to copy 6GB of data onto a hard drive.

Comment: You may want to search Google/Bing for "InterProcess Communication" (IPC); and you may want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915191/simple-ipc-between-c-and-python-cross-platform) Stackoverflow post

Comment: Depending on how large a code base you have in C++, it might be an idea to use something like [Cython](http://cython.org/).

Comment: @WhiZTiM thx, currently i am thinking about IPC method: Shared memory, leater about sockets or mapping file to memory. 
I know that python dont have pointers, but is there any way to access memory via address ?

Comment: @Bendik about 7k of c++ lines, and it is still growing. atm i am thinking about reading data in python via memory adress

Comment: Do you have two programs or one c++-Library called from Python?

Comment: @Daniel two programs. one c++ and one in python. I am calling python program from c++ via `system("python myPyProg.py _args_");`

Comment: You might want to [embed the python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) in your c++ program, that would allow you to give python code access to its data using [python APIs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/).

Comment: @spectras thank you. i think its the best idea yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First path**: I think the more appropriate way for you to go is [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html). You can create a shared library, and then load the functions of the shared library in Python, and fill all the data containers you want in Python.

In Windows, you can create a DLL, and in Linux you can create a shared .so library.

Now this has the advantage that this will be independent of your Python version.

**Second path**: I think it's less appropriate but you can get it to work, which is the [Python C Extension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html). With this, you can call Python data containers (`PyObject`s) and fill them inside C.

However, the code you compile here will always need to be linked to Python libraries.

**Which one to use?**:

- Use ctypes if you have some functions you want to call in C/C++, and then do the rest of the work in Python.
- Use Python C Extension if you have some functions you want to call in Python, and you want to do the rest in C/C++.

With both options, you can transfer huge blocks of memory between C++ and Python without necessarily involving any disk read/write operations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup it helps. Thank you, btw great nick.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 Glad it helps. Btw, there are many wrappers that make using C Extension easier, like Boost and SWIG. Consider these too. I just remember them now. Cheers!