# Appropriate approach for Message Queue / Scheduled tasks in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, mq

I'm wondering what criteria would need to be considered when we need to use some kind of task queue in a django project, I'm thinking in performace, development speed, flexibility, etc.

I've been using [Celery+RabbitMQ](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [Django-ztask+ZeroMQ](https://github.com/dmgctrl/django-ztask) indistinctly for a while (I'm sure there are another good ones), but I haven't an accurate canon for picking up the most suitable in each case.

Could you provide some peculiarities for each of them that allows the user chooses between them?, does it might include some another stable MQ approaches as well?

Comment: Ok, I'm no expert on this subject - but I think this is completely unrelated to Django. Django can work with pretty much anything, I'm thinking you won't feel a whole lot of difference. What you should be asking yourself is what would you like to achieve - or in other words, what MQ library (err... pacakge?) you want to use. See, ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ have [different strong-points and capabilities](http://java.dzone.com/articles/concise-comparison-rabbitmq) which means you should choose the one [that fits your use-case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4878703/2387772)

Comment: I'm not agree with you, because the broker is not the most/unique part of this issue, as you can see on my question there are some other points: "...development speed, flexibility..." and this is relative to Django (code maintenance, possibilities of the third-party django library, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide much but I have used two different solutions, Celery+Redis and Celery+RabbitMQ.

I tried RabbitMQ first and after getting all its dependencies installed and spending some time wading through configs I got it working. It worked well, didn't drop anything, but I was always nervous about restarting (either it or the server) because I was never completely sure it would come back up. I'm sure that's my fault, but I couldn't work out what I'd done wrong.

So I thought I'd give Redis a try. Installed and configured it in about 3 minutes and it has worked without any of my attention since.

Now if only there was something easier to configure than Celery...

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for posting your experiences, I'll have them in mind. Although your answer is pointed to the brokers, i mean, the MQ servers. I'm looking for a more complete approach that includes the integration with Django, in this case you just mentioned Celery, but there are lot of options. Anyway, thanks a lot for your points, undoubtedly I will have them into account.