# Is there any specific drawbacks or issues when using Azure Service Bus on Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

I'm trying to create a table of comparison of different messaging queue, from opensource to proprietary. and I'm trying to identify the issues and disadvantages of Azure Service Bus without availing the standard and premium tier. I would like to ask this question to those who experienced implementing it on their own application.

I tried researching for related topics but i cant find reliable resource.

I'm expecting a list of possible issue and disadvantages in general in any of this areas; features, limitations, experience, maturity, community, and performance.

Comment: I'm not sure what drawbacks you're looking for. ASB is a broker, can be accessed from Kubernetes or any other cluster.

Comment: @SeanFeldman i edited my my question i hope this will add information to my question. sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service bus is just a medium to deliver messages from issuer to the receiver. it doesnt matter when they both are as long as they can talk to the service bus. your application can talk to service bus from inside the container just fine.

Comment: hi, i'm a beginner on azure, thanks for the time answering my question. may i ask what do you mean by "Service bus is just a medium"? i'm a bit confused. is it different from a message queue like ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ?

Comment: in principle - not

Comment: do you have reliable resource there where i can see this principles that you have mention? I don't get it sorry.

Comment: can we say that Azure service bus and ZeroMQ is different because Azure service bus in on network level on top of ZeroMQ which is on application level? is that a correct perspective?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731233/activemq-or-rabbitmq-or-zeromq-or also, consider accepting this answer ;)